# Linq 2 sql - Compare a table and a List<>

Tags: c#, linq, asp.net-web-api, linq-to-sql, sql-server-2014

So, I've got a table `User (Id, Username, Email,...)` in my database, which has a lot of records in it (over 100k).

And I want to compare it with a `List<long>` of `userId`'s. That list has about 5K `userId` in it.

I need to get the records from DB which exists in my list in a quick and efficient way. Using `Where` (and converting `List` to `HashSet`) is not an option, as it creates tremendously big query, and also slow. I tried using `Join` operator but it also creates an inefficient query.

Is there a way to achieve this simply (or else) so that performance remains good, such as creating a temporary table out of the list and then joining it with the `Users` table? Or any other approach?

Comment: Put the list data into the database in a temporary table with proper indexes and execute a query that combines the two tables. The database is *faster* than any in-memory operation you can perform on the client using dictonaries and hash sets. That's because it uses better structures and algorithms (eg btrees), knows the statistics of both tables and can select the best algorithm to join the tables

Comment: To put it another way, joining a 5K and a 100K table isn't a lot. A *small* data mart could have such joins between customers and sales. A lot is when you start talking about million-to-million table joins.

Comment: SQL Server 2014 offers another possibility, using in-memory tables for the smaller set. SQL Server 2016 SP1 offers columnstores and in-memory tables even for *Express* and *LocalDB* editions (ie for free).

Comment: "Put the list data into the database in a temporary table with proper indexes and execute a query that combines the two tables." - Can you provide code example for this using Linq2Sql. I've heard there is no such thing as temp tables in Linq2Sql. Thanks.

Comment: Also, these Lists of user Ids will depend of the user who is making the API call. So, many users can make that query at the same time, with different input.

Comment: Well performance won't be good because just sending 5K long numbers will take time and might create out of memory exceptions with big number of users. You might want to try pagination to split it in smaller chunks. Since on a high frequency server no matter what you do just garbage collection on 5K user object will slow you down at some point.